# Small path enclosing a point $p$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, surfaces, riemann-surfaces

Can anyone help me see why this statement is true

> Let $p$ be a point of a Riemann surface $X$, and let $S$ be a subset of $X$ whose closure does not contain $p$, then theres is a closed path $\gamma$ on $X$ with the following properties, $\gamma
> $ is $1-1$ and its image lies inside the domain $U$ of a chart $\phi:U \rightarrow V$ on $X$, the closed path $\phi \circ \gamma$ has winding number $1$ about $\phi(p)$, no point of $S$ wich lies in the domain of $U$ is mapped to the interior of $\phi\circ \gamma$.

I have tried to since why this is true but couldnt come up with a proof, any help is aprecciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Just take a coordinate disk centered at $p$ disjoint from $\bar S$. (You can certainly use the metric space structure to deduce this, but it's not needed.)

Comment: Yes that was what i was thiking but how do i know that i can create a path there with these conditions?

Comment: What is the obvious path to choose?

Comment: I dont know if this is overkill maybe i am missing something , but i would maybe take an epsilon ball around the point that is contained in the open set and choose the path that gives me the boundary of the ball.

Comment: Sure, any circle centered at $p$ in the interior of that coordinate disk.